# Installing Ganache.appx on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, appx, truffle, consensys-truffle

I am using the following command in PowerShell to install Truffle's Ganache on my Windows 10 machine:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\mabel\Downloads\Ganache.appx"
```

Whenever I run that command I get the following error:

```
    Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFD, A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied.
    Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694 from:  (Ganache.appx)
    failed with error 0x80073CFD. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment
    issues.
    NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 1e4d6f55-8379-0000-3191-4d1e7983d301 in the Event Log or use
    the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 1e4d6f55-8379-0000-3191-4d1e7983d301
    At line:1 char:1
    + Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\mabel\Downloads\Ganache.appx"
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\mabel\Downloads\Ganache.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exceptio
       n
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I digged a bit deeper for a diagnosis and ran the command Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 1e4d6f55-8379-0000-3191-4d1e7983d301, and got the following log details:

```
Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
1/1/2018 8:13:38 PM       301          The calling process is powershell.exe
1/1/2018 8:13:38 PM       603          Started deployment Add operation on a package with main parameter: Ganache.appx and
                                       Options: 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
                                       deployment issues.
1/1/2018 8:13:41 PM       157          The app package signature was validated for core content of the app package published
                                       by CN=Consensys Inc, O=Consensys Inc, L=New York, S=New York, C=US. Payload won't be
                                       validated until the files are read.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       170          The streaming reader was created successfully for app package
                                       Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\edc8d325-87ef-
                                       46b9-93c2-cf029ff3f8f4_S-1-5-21-2104190792-3376611798-3824734217-1001_1.rslc for Add
                                       Operation on Package Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       607          Deployment Add operation on package Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694 has been
                                       de-queued and is running for user DESKTOP-8NHB92D\mabel.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       613          Adding uri to the list of Uris: file:///C:/Users/mabel/Downloads/Ganache.appx.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       605          The last successful state reached was BundleProcessed. Failure occurred before
                                       reaching the next state Indexed.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       401          Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package
                                       Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694 from:  (Ganache.appx)  failed with error
                                       0x80073CFD. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
                                       deployment issues.
1/1/2018 8:13:42 PM       404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694 with
                                       error 0x80073CFD. The specific error text for this failure is: Deployment Add
                                       operation with target volume C: on Package Ganache_1.0.1.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694 from:
                                       (Ganache.appx)  failed with error 0x80073CFD. See
                                       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment
                                       issues.
```

The windows forum recommended me to make sure Windows is fully updated, the last time I updated it was an hour ago.

From the link in the error it says "A specified install prerequisite couldn't be satisfied." I have all the prerequisites to install and run testrpc/ganache cmd line. Are there any steps I need to take before installing Ganache UI?

Comment: Well the link in your log allows you to decode the error: _"A specified install prerequisite couldn't be satisfied."_

Comment: I visited to that link (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160), the problem is that I am not sure what they're referring to when they say a prerequisite couldn't be satisfied. Is there a step I have to do before installing ganache? I am installing ganache on a windows 10 machine, and it has all the prerequisites to run testrpc/ganache command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a ganache source and build it by yourself
https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache

1. Clone this repo
2. Run npm install
3. Run npm start

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, because my windows version was not updated.

Open the .appx file as a zip file
In the root is a file: AppxManifest.xml

There is an optional section on prerequisites.
But before that is a dependencies entry with a minimum windows version.

  `<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14316.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14316.0" />
  </Dependencies>`

Then I checked in powershell to get my dot version:

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      10240  0
```

14316 > 10240, so my OS is too old.

Comment: I see so Windows has to be fully updated before proceeding.

Comment: did it work for you @MabelOza

Answer (score 2):

In case you want an executable file, You will find an executable file [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases), named `ganache-setup-1.3.0.exe`